# How to avoid having to re-permission 3rd-party apps every time MacOS is upgraded

Tags: security, permission, 3rd-party

I'm currently using MacOS 11.7.8.

I make use of a small number of 3rd-party apps. When first installing a few of these 3rd-party apps, I understand that I have to go to "System Preferences => Security and Privacy" and grant permission for each of the apps to access my MacOS system. Of course, I understand why this is necessary.

However, every time I upgrade MacOS, I am again forced to repeat this permissioning exercise for each of these particular 3rd-party apps. I find this to be annoying, and I consider it to be a waste of my time and effort.

Is there any way that I can flag these 3rd-party apps to be automatically re-permissioned every time that I perform a MacOS upgrade?

Thank you very much in advance for any ideas and suggestions.

Comment: How are you upgrading? Migration Assistant should take care of all permissions listed in System Settings. I've been using Migration Assistant on my macOS systems since the macOS Public Beta, so it is perfectly safe, works wonderfully well, and --considering the size of todays drives-- doesn't leave much cruft behind.

Comment: It's not normal to have to re-allow applications after an update -- neither for point updates or major versions. If you're just doing a default update on an existing disk, then the installer will update the OS and leave all your files and settings in place. No need to migrate anything. You can grant permission more quickly by choosing "Open" from a right-click (possibly holding Command, I forget). What apps are these? Can you list them?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that Migration Assistant could simply upgrade my current Mac to a newer MacOS version. I thought it was only useful for transferring my Mac software to a different Mac machine. Up until now, I have always simply ugraded my MacOS version by clicking on the "Update" button when I get the upgrade notification. Thank you very much!

Comment: To @benwiggy: I am always asked to re-permission the MacFUSE software that I use to manage sshFS mounts. Actually, I think that's the only app now for which I have to do this.

Comment: Does it use kernel extensions? That may require extra security. They're being deprecated, so you could see if there's a newer version that uses a different process. Perhaps ask the makers for help.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need/can use Migration Assistant just to update an existing installation.

Comment: I'm not sure if it requires kernel extensions. I'm using the latest version, for sure. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @benwiggy, I now know the solution to my problem.

The only app where I've now been having this issue is the "MacFUSE" app, which indeed makes use of a kernel extension, and @benwiggy pointed out that this is probably the reason for my having to re-permission the app every time I upgrade MacOS.

I now have found an alternative FUSE implementation for MacOS which doesn't rely on a kernel extension:

https://www.fuse-t.org/

I have installed this other version of FUSE, and it is working with no problem, and so now, I'm optimistic that I will no longer have to re-permission anything the next time I upgrade MacOS.